# Redirection domain1.com to domain2.com/page

Tags: .htaccess, seo, redirect, data-migration

I've been searching for a while and have seen some similar questions but nothing exactly what I'm looking for.

I have two domains, let's say **domain1.com** and **domain2.com**. I am going to be migrating the content from **domain1.com** to  the folder, **domain2.com/page**. Beyond that, ALL slugs will stay exactly the same. So, I'm going to want **domain1.com** to redirect to **domain2.com/page** , and any path like **domain1.com/whatever** to redirect to **domain2.com/page/whatever** and so forth. Would this be the code needed, or something else?

```
RewriteEngine On

# First condition, requested resource is not an existing file in domain1.com (this condition can be removed if needed)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Second condition, requested resource is not an existing directory file in domain1.com (this condition can be removed if needed)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Third condition, slug must exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$

# Do the redirection
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this :

```
Redirect HTTP://domain1.com HTTP://domain2.com/pages
```

Don't forget about the spaces.